# How to install @swc/core-linux-musl on windows, to make it work in docker container?

Tags: docker, next.js

I'am working on windows. I docernize `Next.js` with `Typescript` app.
Here is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine

# create directory where our application will be run
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

# copy our files into directory
COPY . /usr/src

# install dependences
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run" ,"dev"]
```

**During development I bind host catalogue to container by `--mount type=bind,source=d:/apps/library.next.js/,target=/usr/src`**. When I start container I get error: `error - Failed to load SWC binary for linux/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc`.

That's fine, I understand error and know what to do. To fix this I need to install `@swc/cli @swc/core @swc/core-linux-musl`, but I can't doing it because npm complain:

> ERR! code EBADPLATFORM npm
> ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @swc/core-linux-musl@1.2.42: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

How to install it on windows, or how to change docker setup to make it work? **I must install it locally then it will be linked (by binding !) into container.**

---

My workaround for now is to get into container by `docker exec -it <id> /bin/sh` then manually type `npm install -save-dev @swc/cli @swc/core @swc/core-linux-musl`. But doing that every time I recreate container is annoying.

Comment: Have you tried? RUN npm i -f

Comment: @a_e it works. I forced `npm` to install despite error. In npm docs about install there is not `-f` option. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install.

Comment: @a_e could you write your suggestion as a answer. I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state: The `-f` or `--force` will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk. And it should be in the docs v6 legacy, the one you posted and v8 version. (See the section after --package-lock-only. It comes with an example `npm install sax --force`). So, you shouldn't have issues with that every time your container is recreating.

Comment: Just for notice: there is drawback in this solution. I have to use `-f` for every time when working with `npm`.